# Remove matched Rows from two Datatable C# ( performance optimize)

Tags: asp.net, performance, c#-4.0, datatable

Here i have two `DataTable`

- dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays
- dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks

each having 10k+ values. I need to delete matched rows.
Below code works fine

```
foreach (DataRow rw in dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays.Select())
 {
    DateTime dateFromRange=Convert.ToDateTime(rw[0].ToString());
    string strPrnt = dateFromRange.ToShortDateString();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks.Select())
    {
      DateTime getDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[0].ToString());
      string strchild = getDate.ToShortDateString();
       if (strPrnt == strchild)
       {
          rw.Delete();
        }
       }
 }
```

Want to know if any better alternative suggestion, coz `Foreach` loop takes time when bulk data is there

Answer (score 1):

You can have both DataTables ordered by date and advance on both at the same time keeping the date as reference.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var CurrDate = Datetime.MinDate;
while true {
   while (dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays[i].Date <= CurrDate) {
      i++
   }
   while (dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks[j].Date <= CurrDate) {
      j++
   }
   If (dtTotalDateRangeExcludeSundays[i].Date == dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks[j].Date) {
      // delete
   }
   CurrDate = Min( dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks[j].Date, dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks[j].Date )
}
```

You have to add all the checks for indexes out of range and other safeties. Do you get the idea?

**Or**
You can delete all matching rows in one sql statement (if applicable)

```
Delete from TotalDateRangeExcludeSundays where Date in (Select date from AbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, pls can you explain it more , here in both the `datatable` data having different timespan, and `dtAbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks`  is in random order

Comment: Added a sample pseudo-code (very basic to explain the idea). You have to get both DataTables ordered by date to work.

Comment: thanks, but i dnt think `Delete from TotalDateRangeExcludeSundays where Date in (Select date from AbsentsLeavesHolidaysWorks)`  this will work, coz  there datatable are runtime generate depending upon some condition tooo,  will try ur 1st option n **+1** for that, also want to know  is there any trick using LinQ ??

Comment: You can use Linq too, but you wont gain any performance. The code will be nicer.